# Pass data to another file and call function from that file in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a function in a separate JavaScript file and I'm calling it in a React component. function calling is working fine but am facing issue while passing values to that JavaScript file.

For ex:

I have the 3 components like below,

```
//home.js
getAllData(key) { //here the 'key' is getting from dropdown that is present in home.js itself.
    axios.get('<URL>')
    .then(data)
    {
        const resonposedata = new Map(data.response); // i need to pass this data to the Javascript file (supportfunction.js).
    }
}


//supportfunction.js

const responseData = responseDataFromAPI;  //Here I need the 'resonposedata' which is received from the API in home.js
export const searchDataByType = (n)=>{
  //I'll use the `responseData` to find the values
}

export const searchDataBySize = (n)=>{
  //I'll use the `responseData` to find the values
}


//searchProducts.js
import { searchDataByType, searchDataBySize } from './supportfunction'

onDropdown1Change(event) {
        searchDataByType("x"); 
    }

onDropdown2Change(event) {
        searchDataBySize("y"); 
    }
```

In above example, I need the 'resonposedata' in searchProducts.js file. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need the responseData on your home.js component?

Comment: How the components are related to each other?

Comment: @joseluismurillorios, I have responseData in home.js. I need it in supportfunction.js.

Comment: @ravibagul91, Home.js is the parent component and I searchProducts.js is child of it. I have a api call in home.js and it updates if one of the dropdown is changed in home.js. I am using that result via functions calls (api response) in searchProducts.js. But i have the functions in supportfunction.js since am using the same function in some other places also.

Comment: Store response data in state and pass data to child (searchProducts) component. In child as you are already importing functions from `supportfunction` component, you can pass the response data to that functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something to control your global state and some async functions to wait for the responses and then render the changes, but here's one approach you can try:

```
//home.js
import { getData } from 'supportfunction.js';

getAllData(key) {
  // here the 'key' is getting from dropdown that is present in home.js itself.
  getData('<URL>');
}


//supportfunction.js

//Here I need the 'resonposedata' which is received from the API in home.js
export let responseData = null;

export const getData = (url) => {
  axios.get(url)
    .then((data) => {
      responseData = new Map(data.response); // i need to pass this data to the Javascript file (supportfunction.js).
    });
}

export const searchDataByType = (n) => {
  // if (responseData) {}
}

export const searchDataBySize = (n) => {
  // if (responseData) {}
}


//searchProducts.js
import { searchDataByType, searchDataBySize } from './supportfunction'

onDropdown1Change(event) {
  searchDataByType("x");
}

onDropdown2Change(event) {
  searchDataBySize("y");
}
```